# Web App Not Running on Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, web-part

I have 3rd party web app installed onto my SharePoint 2013 Server. Everything is setup and I can use the app as expected.

When I add the app to the homepage of my main site it does not load, it wont dynamically size and the autoplay feature it has does not work.

If I load the same app onto a subsite it works fine. It is an IE based issue as Chrome works fine.

How can I check the differences between the two pages Developer tools is not helping that much.

Comment: I assume the app has debug strings. Have a look in the ULS logs for more details.

Comment: Will take a look, I just find it odd that there is a single site which it will not work on.